# Setting parameters of block "custcode/System Outputs" programmatically

Tags: matlab

How can I set the code for the block "custcode/System Outputs" programmatically? I receive an error "Size arguments must be real integers" when opening the block by double-click after running the following:

```
add_block('custcode/System Outputs','model/subsystem')
field = setfield(get_param('model/subsystem/systemOutput','RTWData'),'Top','test');
set_param('Copy_of_model_vergleich_atom/Subsystem1/test','RTWData',field);
```

Comment: Try adding a new line after the string. E,g, ['test' char(10)].

Comment: Actually, thats it. Any idea where this comes from?